FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'bool_only=None') is deprecated
I have a Dataframe that looks something like this:



Column A
Column B
Name




Cell 1
Cell 2
albert


Cell 3
Cell 4
einstein


Cell 5
Cell 6
einstein



My Goal is to check if the dataframe contains valid rows (== all columns are filled with values) and if in the column name in this row contains the value albert.
If i run dataframe[dataframe["NAME"] == "albert"].any().all() it shows a warning.

FutureWarning: Dropping of nuisance columns in DataFrame reductions (with 'bool_only=None') is deprecated; in a future version this will raise TypeError.  Select only valid columns before calling the reduction.

I don't get where this FutureWarning comes from and how to solve it.
For everyone wondering, I use pandas version 1.3.5 because there are some other dependencies in my project that requires this old version.
In order to use the default settings from pandas version 2.2, I already tried to set the parameter bool_only=False so that the statement looks like this:
dataframe[dataframe["NAME"] == "albert"].any(bool_only=False).all()
But this does not work. Instead it shows the following error:

TypeError: Cannot perform reduction 'any' with string dtype

Am I missing an easy way to achieve my initial goal?
Sorry for my bad english.

What about dataframe[dataframe['Name'] == 'albert'].astype(bool).any().all()? But since your Name column is necessarily "albert", wouldn't this always yield True anyway?

Yes that is true. It would always yield True. I assume that there is maximal one row in the dataframe that contains albert. It can happen that there is no row. I need the boolean value in an if condition for further action. Thank you very much, it was the typeconversion that was needed! But nonetheless i wonder why the second error occurs.

If your goal is to check that at least one row contains "albert" you can simplify to dataframe['Name'].eq('albert').any().

Btw, notna() might be better suited than astype(bool) if you want to consider NaNs

I used your first simplification and it works like a charme. Thank you very much!

You can simplify further: 'albert' in df['Name'] ;)
